# I don't get the error in line 1 "! File ended while scanning use of \frame." ? (beamer)

Tags: beamer

I want to do a presentation with Tex, and wanted to proof how it looks like, but I don't get the error , is it a syntax or something else ?

```
%\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{tabular}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{multimedia}
% \usepackage{movie15}

\usetheme[footline=infoline]{own}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamerfont{footline}{size= \footnotesize}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
 \vbox{}\vskip-3ex
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.80ex,leftskip=0.4cm,dp=0.6ex,]{frametitle}
\usebeamerfont{header_font_subsection}{\insertframetitle}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}

%%%
%%% Ein paar Farben
%%%
\definecolor{lila}{rgb}{0.9,0,1}

\definecolor{gruen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{braun}{rgb}{0.5,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{farbe1}{rgb}{0.75,0.34,0}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.196,0.196,0.694}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{1,0.3,0.1} % {0.81,0.36,0.36}                    %{0.698,0.13,0.13} 
 % \definecolor{myred}{rgb}{220,20,60}
\newcommand{\com}{\color{magenta}}
\newcommand{\coblass}{\color{grey}}
\newcommand{\clb}{\color{blue}}

%%%
%%% Griechische Buchstaben. Die normalen sehen nicht gut aus
%%% auf Folien
%%%
% \newcommand{\MyGamma}{\mathit{\Gamma}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyGamma}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyDelta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyTheta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyLambda}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyXi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyPi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MySigma}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyUpsilon}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyPhi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyPsi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MyOmega}{\mathord}{upgreek}{"0A}
\newcommand{\Om}{{\Omega}}
\newcommand{\al}{{\alpha}}
\newcommand{\Ga}{{\Gamma}}
\newcommand{\la}{{\lambda}}    
\newcommand{\La}{{\Lambda}}   
\def\si{\sigma}
\def\tto{\leadsto}

\newcommand{\Domain}{{\color{blue} \MyOmega}}
\newcommand{\Boundary}{{\color{gruen} \MyGamma}}
\newcommand{\cob}{\color{myblue}}
\newcommand{\cor}{\color{myred}}  % \newcommand{\cor}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\cog}{\color{gruen}}
\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\E}{{\sf E}}
\newcommand{\supp}{\mathop{\rm{supp}}} 
\def\diam{\mathop{\rm diam}}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\II{\mathbb{I}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\bx}{{\bf x}} 

\def\lsim{\raisebox{-1ex}{$~\stackrel{\textstyle<}{\sim}~$}}
\def\gsim{\raisebox{-1ex}{$~\stackrel{\textstyle>}{\sim}~$}}

\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\ts}{\textstyle}
\newcommand{\beqn}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\eeqn}{\end{equation}}
\renewcommand{\lll}{\langle} 
\newcommand{\rr}{\rangle}
\def\t{\tilde}

%--------------------------------------
% Inhalt der Titelseite erstellen
%--------------------------------------
\author[\footnotesize Max Mustermann]{\small Max Mustermann}
\vspace*{-5mm}

\institute[Univ. of Berlin]{\\[-3mm]
\footnotesize
Seminar zur Numerik im SS 2018, Universit\"at of Berlin
}

\title[Sobolev-Orthogonalpolynome]
{Sobolev-Orthogonalpolynome}

\date[{15. Mai2018}] {
\\[-6mm]

 \footnotesize 
 15.Mai 2018\\[5mm]
 \flushleft
 \pause

 {\cor Ziel} dieses Vortrags: Motivation der Thematik 

 \begin{itemize}
 \item[$\bullet$] Sobolev-Orthogonalpolynome: Theorie und Anwendungen aus   [G1]
 \item[$\bullet$] Sobolev-Orthogonalpolynome: Verwendung der Matlab-              Programme aus [G2]
  \end{itemize}
  \vspace{5mm}
  % \pause

  \tiny
  {\cor Verwendete Literatur} (zus\"atzlich zu Originalarbeiten): 
  \begin{itemize}
  %
  \item[{[G1]}] W. Gautschi, Orthogonal Polynomials, Oxford University    Press, 2004.
  %
  \item[{[G2]}]  W. Gautschi, Orthogonal Polynomials in Matlab, SIAM, 2016.


  %
   \end{itemize}
    }
    %--------------------------------------
     % Titelseite
   %--------------------------------------
  \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[t]

   \maketitle

   \end{frame}

  %--------------------------------------------
  \begin{frame}[t]
  % \centerline{\small\cor Orthogonalpolynome}
  \vspace*{2mm}
  \footnotesize

  {\cob Definition} 

  \begin{itemize}
  \item[$\bullet$]
  \item[$\bullet$] $\ldots$
  \end{itemize}
  \vspace{5mm}
  \pause

  {\cob Definition}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item[$\bullet$] 
  \item[$\bullet$] 
  \item[$\bullet$] 
  \item[$\bullet$]
  \item[$\bullet$] 
  \item[$\bullet$] $\ldots$
  \end{itemize}
  \vspace{5mm}



  \end{frame}
  %--------------------------------------------

  \begin{frame}[t]
  \centerline{\small\cor Motivation}
  \vspace*{2mm}
  \footnotesize

  \centerline{\small\cor Definition & Eigenschaften}
  \item Sei $\Bbb P :=\{relle \quad Polynome\}$ für ein Paar $u,v \in    \Bbb P$ definieren wir 
  $(1.1) (u,v)_S= \int_{\Bbb R}u(t)v(t) d\lambda_0(t)+\cdots+\int_{\Bbb  R}u^{(s)}(t)v^{(s)}(t) d\lambda_s(t)$ wobei $s\le 1$ $d\lambda_i$ positive  Maße (mit nicht notwendigerweise selben Trägern) als Sobolev inneres  Produkt\\[1mm]
  \pause


  \vspace{6mm}
  \pause
  \begin{frame}[t]
  \centerline{\small\cor Motivation}
  \vspace*{2mm}
  \footnotesize

  \centerline{\small\cor Definition und Eigenschaften}
  \item Die Norm ist definiert durch $\lVert u\rVert_S=\sqrt{(u,u)_S}=    \sqrt{\sum_{\sigma=1}^s\int_{\Bbb R}(u^{(\sigma)}(t))^2} d\lambda_{\sigma}(t)$\\ sofern $s\le 1$, erfüllt $(1.1)$ nicht länger die Shift-Eigenschaft.
  Für $s=1$, z.B. ist $(tu,v)_S=(u,tv)_S=\int_{\Bbb R}(uv'-u'v)(t) d\lambda_1(t)$ 
  Wähle $u(t)=1$ und $v(t)=t$ $\Rightarrow \int_{\Bbb R}d\lambda_1(t)>0$[1mm]
 \pause


  \vspace{6mm}
  \pause
  %\centerline{\small\cor } 
  %
  %{\cor Zusammenfassung und Ausblick} 
  %\begin{itemize}
  %Test
  %\end{itemize}
  %\end{frame}

  %--------------------------------------------

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is not compilable. Could you please remove all unnecessary parts and make it compilable ? I mean, remove styles and other parts that people here cannot have

Comment: You have multiple issues, unclosed `frame` environments and loose `\item` it won't work this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination  of several problems:

- You cannot begin a new frame before closing the previous one
- you cannot us `\item` outside of an itemize ennvironment
- your are missing `\end{frame}` at the end of your code.
- & has a special meaning in tex, if you want to print this sign, you need to use `\&`
- Obsolete command `\Bbb`; `\mathbb` should be used instead

Not a problem, but

- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- you should not use `\centerline`
- all these manual fontzise and spacing command should be unnecessary - for example, if the author should be in small, use `\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}` instead of `{\small Max Mustermann}`
- using `\vspace*{-5mm}` in the preamble does not make any sense
- the `[1mm]` after you math mode does not make sense if you don't use a line break in front of it
- you should not misuse the date field for the outline of your talk. If you want this on the title page, simply add it after `\maketitle`
- (this is merely my personal opinion) nobody will be able to read your slides if you use such a small font.

Here is my cleaned up version:

```
\documentclass[9pt,t,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\footnotesize}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.196,0.196,0.694}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{1,0.3,0.1} 

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=myred}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}

\author{Max Mustermann}
\institute[Univ. of Berlin]{Seminar zur Numerik im SS 2018, Universit\"at of Berlin}
\title{Sobolev-Orthogonalpolynome}
\date{15.Mai 2018}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle

  \pause

  \alert{Ziel} dieses Vortrags: Motivation der Thematik 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Sobolev-Orthogonalpolynome: Theorie und Anwendungen aus   [G1]
    \item Sobolev-Orthogonalpolynome: Verwendung der Matlab-Programme aus [G2]
  \end{itemize}

    \vfill
    \begingroup
        \tiny
    \alert{Verwendete Literatur} (zus\"atzlich zu Originalarbeiten): 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[{[G1]}] W. Gautschi, Orthogonal Polynomials, Oxford University    Press, 2004.
        \item[{[G2]}] W. Gautschi, Orthogonal Polynomials in Matlab, SIAM, 2016.
    \end{itemize}
  \endgroup
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \structure{Definition} 

  \begin{itemize}
      \item 
      \item $\ldots$
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{Definition} 
  \begin{itemize}
      \item
      \item
      \item
      \item
      \item
      \item $\ldots$
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{center}
         \alert{Motivation}

         \alert{Definition \& Eigenschaften}
    \end{center}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Sei $\mathbb{P} :=\{relle \quad Polynome\}$ für ein Paar $u,v \in    \mathbb{P}$ definieren wir 
      $(1.1) (u,v)_S= \int_{\mathbb{R}}u(t)v(t) d\lambda_0(t)+\cdots+\int_{\mathbb{R}}u^{(s)}(t)v^{(s)}(t) d\lambda_s(t)$ wobei $s\le 1$ $d\lambda_i$ positive  Maße (mit nicht notwendigerweise selben Trägern) als Sobolev inneres  Produkt
  \end{itemize}

  \pause

    \begin{center}
         \alert{Motivation}

         \alert{Definition \& Eigenschaften}
    \end{center}

  \begin{itemize}
      \item Die Norm ist definiert durch $\lVert u\rVert_S=\sqrt{(u,u)_S}=    \sqrt{\sum_{\sigma=1}^s\int_{\mathbb{R}}(u^{(\sigma)}(t))^2} d\lambda_{\sigma}(t)$\\ sofern $s\le 1$, erfüllt $(1.1)$ nicht länger die Shift-Eigenschaft.
    Für $s=1$, z.B. ist $(tu,v)_S=(u,tv)_S=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(uv'-u'v)(t) d\lambda_1(t)$ 
    Wähle $u(t)=1$ und $v(t)=t$ $\Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}d\lambda_1(t)>0$
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you really much ! Can you recommend a good beginner video channel or book with examples ?

Comment: @pinkpanther5 The beamer user guide has a nice beginner section at the start called `3 Tutorial: Euclid’s Presentation`, especially 3.15 should be interesting for you. http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf